# How to create an "All" link in a taxonomy menu (block)?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, blocks

I have a taxonomy vocabulary and terms as follow:

Food:
  -Meat
  -Veggies
  -Fruit
  -Dairy

I want to create a menu of taxonomy terms that look like this:

-All
-Meat
-Veggies
-Fruit
-Dairy

... when you are on the "Food" page.

I have tried the Taxonomy Menu and Taxonomy Menu Block modules, but none give me the option to have an "All" link. That's a bit daft innit?

How can you show the user posts/nodes of all terms?

Any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

My opinion:

You can create a new term called `all` and add it to all your related nodes.

Or, 
You may use [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) to create a page to show all nodes, and add that to your menu.